# Sort columns of a data frame by a vector of column names

Tags: r, sorting, vector, dataframe

I have a data.frame that looks like this:
[image]

which has 1000+ columns with similar names.

And I have a vector of those column names that looks like this:
[image]

The vector is sorted by the cluster_id (which goes up to 11).

I want to sort the columns in the data frame such that the columns are in the order of the names in the vector.

A simple example of what I want is that:

**Data:**

```
 A    B    C
 1    2    3
 4    5    6
```

**Vector:**
c("B","C","A")

**Sorted:**

```
 B    C    A
 2    3    1
 5    6    4
```

Is there a fast way to do this?

Comment: @AnandaMahto This is not school homework.... I don't know how to sort the columns other than using loop and check the position of the column name in the vector, and then sort it and make data frame.

Comment: Why pictures of a table? The chance of getting the right answer increases considerably if you give a [reproducable example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Jaap The original data is too large. I can give you a very simple example. Check the edit.

Comment: I have already added a simple example to the question.

Comment: @YilunZhang Did you read the thread about reproducable examples? I'm not asking for your whole dataset. You could for example provide us with a `dput` of a part of your data. For example: dput(head(df))

Comment: @Jaap I have more than 1000 columns, and I cannot get all the data shown. Can't you do with the example I gave?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Brodie's answer does exactly what you're asking for. However, you imply that your data are large, so I will provide an alternative using "data.table", which has a function called `setcolorder` that will change the column order by reference.

Here's a reproducible example.

Start with some simple data:

```
mydf <- data.frame(A = 1:2, B = 3:4, C = 5:6)
matches <- data.frame(X = 1:3, Y = c("C", "A", "B"), Z = 4:6)
mydf
#   A B C
# 1 1 3 5
# 2 2 4 6
matches
#   X Y Z
# 1 1 C 4
# 2 2 A 5
# 3 3 B 6
```

Provide proof that Brodie's answer works:

```
out <- mydf[matches$Y]
out
#   C A B
# 1 5 1 3
# 2 6 2 4
```

Show a more memory efficient way to do the same thing.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)
mydf
#    A B C
# 1: 1 3 5
# 2: 2 4 6

setcolorder(mydf, as.character(matches$Y))
mydf
#    C A B
# 1: 5 1 3
# 2: 6 2 4
```

Answer (score 20):

UPDATE, with reproducible data added by OP:

```
df <- read.table(h=T, text="A    B    C
    1    2    3
    4    5    6")
vec <- c("B", "C", "A")
df[vec]
```

Results in:

```
  B C A
1 2 3 1
2 5 6 4
```

As OP desires.

---

How about:

```
df[df.clust$mutation_id]
```

Where `df` is the data.frame you want to sort the columns of and `df.clust` is the data frame that contains the vector with the column order (`mutation_id`).

This basically treats `df` as a list and uses standard vector indexing techniques to re-order it.

Comment: So you add a new column to df, a column of ordered column names? Then how do you sort the column in this order?

Comment: @YilunZhang I'm not adding a column to `df`.  `df[df.clust$mutation_id]` and `df[df.clust$mutation_id, ]` are completely different.  The first one actually does the same as `df[,df.clust$mutation_id]` (i.e. sorts columns) for reasons related to the dual nature of data frames (they are both lists and data frames).  The second one sorts rows.

Answer (score 2):

A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1's solution didn't work for my data (I've a similar problem that Yilun Zhang) so I found another option:

```
mydf <- data.frame(A = 1:2, B = 3:4, C = 5:6)
#   A B C
# 1 1 3 5
# 2 2 4 6
matches <- c("B", "C", "A") #desired order

mydf_reorder <- mydf[,match(matches, colnames(mydf))]
colnames(mydf_reorder)
#[1] "B" "C" "A"
```

`match()` find the the position of first element on the second one:

```
match(matches, colnames(mydf))
#[1] 2 3 1
```

I hope this can offer another solution if anyone is having problems!