# Identify identical columns in two data frames and extract them in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames; `mRNA` ([here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ZbdQk8Cpu2M08wa0JRUUt6LTA/view)) and `RPPA`([here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ZbdQk8Cpu2Y0JrYUMtQUdjdnM/view)). The `mRNA` data frame has 1,212 columns, while the `RPPA` data frame has 937 columns. All columns names in the `RPPA` data frame appear also in the `mRNA` data frame (but not in the same order). Within the columns, the values are different between the two data frames.
I want to create a `new mRNA` data frame, which will contain the same columns as the `RPPA` data frame, and **will not** contain the columns that do not appear in the ("old") `mRNA` data frame.
An example:

```
mRNA <- data.frame(A=c(25,76,23,45), B=c(56,89,12,452), C=c(45,456,243,5), D=c(13,65,23,16), E=c(17:20), F=c(256,34,0,5))  
RPPA <- data.frame(B=c(46,47,45,49), A=c(51,87,34,87), D=c(76,34,98,23))
```

The expected result would be:

```
> new.mRNA
B     A     D
56    25    13
89    76    65
12    23    23
452   45    16
```

I've tried converting the RPPA column names into a vector, and than use it with the command `mRNA[col.names.vector]`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23141795/r-sort-columns-of-a-data-frame-by-a-vector-of-column-names), but it doesn't work. It gives the error `undefined columns selected`.

Is there a quick way to do it (without functions, loops etc.)?

Comment: Please check if you have leading/lagging spaces in your column names

Comment: @akrun sorry, I'm really new to r. how do I check this?

Comment: @deborah It is easy to check.  `colnames(mRNA); colnames(RPPA)`

Comment: @akrun I don't think I have spaces, but I do have numerous dots. example of column name: **TCGA.3C.AALI.01A.21.A43F.20**. Is that a problem?

Comment: It could be a problem.  Check whether you have the same dots in both of the dataset colum names

Comment: Yes, the dots are the same. I've added a link to the files, if you could maybe view it it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the answers that were posted didn't work for my data. Thanks to both answers posted, and with a little more research, I figured out the answer:
**First,** you need to generate a vector that will include ONLY the column names that appear in BOTH data frames. In order to do that I used the command `intersect` and `Reduce`:

```
target <- Reduce(intersect, list(colnames(raw.mRNA), colnames(RPPA)))
```

Now you can use the answer that was given:

```
new.mRNA <- mRNA[target]
```

and this will generate a new data frame with the right values.
Thank you @akrun and @Titolondon for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can find the dissimilar columns in two data frames as per the below code.

```
col_name=colnames(mRNA[which(!(colnames(mRNA) %in% colnames(RPPA)))])

new_mRNA=mRNA %>% select(-col_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can subset the `mRNA` by the column names of 'RPPA' and assign it to 'RPPA'

```
RPPA[] <- mRNA[names(RPPA)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Subset of a data.frame with a vector should have work.

1. Create a vector of the column name you want to keep
2. Subset you data.frame using this vector

```r
mRNA <- data.frame(A=c(25,76,23,45), B=c(56,89,12,452), C=c(45,456,243,5), D=c(13,65,23,16), E=c(17:20), F=c(256,34,0,5))  
RPPA <- data.frame(B=c(46,47,45,49), A=c(51,87,34,87), D=c(76,34,98,23))  

mRNA
#>    A   B   C  D  E   F
#> 1 25  56  45 13 17 256
#> 2 76  89 456 65 18  34
#> 3 23  12 243 23 19   0
#> 4 45 452   5 16 20   5
RPPA
#>    B  A  D
#> 1 46 51 76
#> 2 47 87 34
#> 3 45 34 98
#> 4 49 87 23
mRNA[, names(RPPA)]
#>     B  A  D
#> 1  56 25 13
#> 2  89 76 65
#> 3  12 23 23
#> 4 452 45 16
```

Comment: How is this answer different from mine?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Actually, both answers are not yet what I'm looking for. When I'm doing akrun's answer, all values in the RPPA data frame are becoming NA's. When I do Titolondon's answer, I get again the error described above (undefined columns selected).

Comment: @deborah I couldn't reproduce your NA's based on the example you provided.  I am getting the expected output as you showed

Comment: @akrun The row names are different between mRNA and RPPA. Could that be the reason?

Comment: @deborah Please try the code on the example you only posted

Comment: @akrun It is working with the example, but not with my actual data... I can't figure what's the problem